# VUE:how to bind multiple tabs to one component and let it activates only one time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, tabs, vue-component

I have those tabs to be created dynamically by results returned from spring boot.
Lets's say, there are 3 tabs generated.

Now I bind one component to those generated tabs.

But, once I click on either one of those tabs, the component will be activated 3 times simultaneously.

Is there anyway I can do to activate the component only once when I click a tab?

The component is fixed, so it is always activated 3 times no mater which tab I click.

//this is where the tabs details are generated:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < logData.length; i++) {
      let log = logData[i];

          let newTabName = ++this.tabIndex + '';

          this.accCopFinanceSheetEditTabs.push({
            title: log.sheetName,
            name: newTabName,
            content: 'accCopFinanceSheetEdit'
          });
        }
```

//this is to bind the component to all tabs

```
  <el-tab-pane
    v-for="(item, index) in accCopFinanceSheetEditTabs"
    :key="item.name"
    :label="item.title"
    :name="item.name"
  >
    <accCopFinanceSheetEdit v-bind:copFinanceSheetEditInfo="copFinanceSheetEditInfo"></accCopFinanceSheetEdit>
  </el-tab-pane>
```

Comment: Could you show the code snippet of what you have done so as to help you better?

Comment: thx, I've updated the question please back to have a look;)